# Не могу обратиться к элементам activity_main

Tags: android, kotlin

Хочу изменить текст в textView через MainActivity.kt, но мой код не видит элемент. Пробовал с кнопками также, но не помогло.

Прилагаю вам MainActivity.kt

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
    fun toastMe(view: View) {
        val myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

        myToast.show()
    }

    fun countMe(view: View) {
        val countString = textView.text.toString()
        var count: Int = Integer
        count++

        textView.text = count.ToString()

    }
}
```

ActivityMain

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/screenBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:text="@string/hello_worldText"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    <Button
        android:onClick="toastMe"
        android:id="@+id/toast_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="@color/bottunBackground"
        android:text="toast"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/count_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bottunBackground"
        android:text="count"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/random_button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/toast_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/random_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:background="@color/bottunBackground"
        android:text="random"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: Что значит "не видит"? Что в этом коде должно изменять текст? Что происходит при запуске? Что должно происходить? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Эникейщик не видит, это значит, что я обращаюсь к элементу по id, но почему-то он не обращается. Выделяет красным. Мне надо изъять из textView текст и потом добавить другой

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45005003/7540461  ну или же используйте `findViewById`

Comment: если выделяет красным, то надо подвести туда курсор и прочитать причину выделения

Answer (score 0):

Твой код не может найти элемент TextView потому что не инициализировал его в коде

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
```

Это должно быть добавлено в метод onCreate() **после вызова** setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). Также, в методе countMe(), исправь строку

```
var count: Int = Integer
```

на

```
var count: Int = Integer.parseInt(countString)
```

или

```
var count: Int = countString.toInt()
```

и исправь

```
textView.text = count.ToString()
```

на

```
textView.text = count.toString()
```

Comment: "перед вызовом setContentView" - вы уверены?

Comment: опечатка надо после